# Looping through multiple column : optimization

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to Macro/VBA. We have a requirement ,where I need to check different condition against multiple column and if the conditions are met, then update the final column.

I was able to code it(copied and edited) and it is working fine against small no. of records. The problem is that ,my file has 20000+ records and now the VBA is taking around 40-45 min to update "Call Down Start Date_CUSTOM" column.

Is there anyway to optimize the code or make it to run faster?

```
Sub Macro3_Call_down_start_date_custom()

Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    For i = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If .ListColumns("Activation Status").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "No" And _
            .ListColumns("Call Down Start Date").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "" Then
            .ListColumns("Call Down Start Date_CUSTOM").DataBodyRange(i).Value = .ListColumns("Date Added").DataBodyRange(i).Value + 3
            
        ElseIf .ListColumns("Activation Status").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "Yes" And _
            .ListColumns("Publish Date").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "" And _
            .ListColumns("Time to 1st Publish POC Status").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "No First POC" Then
            .ListColumns("Call Down Start Date_CUSTOM").DataBodyRange(i).Value = .ListColumns("Activation Date").DataBodyRange(i).Value
        Else
           .ListColumns("Call Down Start Date_CUSTOM").DataBodyRange(i).Value = .ListColumns("Call Down Start Date").DataBodyRange(i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Use Variant arrays and loop those and fill another array that you bulk load.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response  Scott,I am sorry totally new to this VBA thing.Can you elaborate a little bit more on this.What is Variant array suppose to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set lc = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns
set range1 = lc("Activation Status").DataBodyRange
set range2 = lc("Call Down Start Date").DataBodyRange
set range3 = lc("Call Down Start Date_CUSTOM").DataBodyRange
set range4 = lc("Date Added").DataBodyRange

on error goto CATCH
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
For i = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
  if range1(i).Value = "No" And _
  range2(i).Value = "" then
    range3(i).Value = range4(i).Value + 3
  elseif
    ...
  else
    ...
  end if
next i
end with

CATCH: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end sub
```